# How to save new background color via `colorpicker` to `localStorage`?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know there's a lot of similar questions.. I've tried them but I really can't incorporate it to my project.

I'm trying to save to `localStorage` the new `background-color` selected using the native `colorpicker`.

I'm almost there but I just can't figure out how to make it work.

Please see my code so far:

```js
function changeBgColor(color) {
  if (color) window.localStorage.setItem('bgColor', color);
  else if (!(color = window.localStorage.getItem('bgColor'))) return;

  document.getElementById('colorpicker').addEventListener('input', function() {

    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("card-bg")
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].style.background = this.value;
    }

  })

}
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => changeBgColor());
```

```css
.card1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #222;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="card1 card-bg">Set A</div>
<div class="card1 card-bg">Set A</div>
<div class="card1 card-bg">Set A</div>

<br>

<input type="color" id="colorpicker" onselect="changeBgColor();">
```

The important feature for me are:

1. To change background color using input="color"
2. Use `class` selector since I have multiple divs I want to target with the same input
3. Save the value to `localStorage`

That's all really. I just need to figure out the part where the value gets saved to `localStorage`.

After I make this work, I will need to replicate it for a different set of divs..

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: I think it's the single = in your if check, should be a double ==

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If check had `=` assignment instead of `==` comparison

Here is a working refactored snippet:

```js
let pretend_local_storage = null

function setupBackgroundColorChange() {
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".card-bg")
  document.getElementById('colorpicker').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    color = e.target.value
    if (color === pretend_local_storage) return
    pretend_local_storage = color
    elements.forEach((element) => element.style.background = color)
  })
}
window.onDOMContentLoaded = setupBackgroundColorChange();
```

```css
.card1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #222;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="card1 card-bg">Set A</div>
<div class="card1 card-bg">Set A</div>
<div class="card1 card-bg">Set A</div>

<br>

<input type="color" id="colorpicker" onselect="changeBgColor();">
```

Local Storage example:

```js
localStorage.getItem('bgColor', null)
function setupBackgroundColorChange() {
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".card-bg")
    setColor(elements, localStorage.getItem('bgColor', '#000'))
    document.getElementById('colorpicker').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
        color = e.target.value
        if (color === localStorage.getItem('bgColor')) return
        localStorage.setItem('bgColor', color)
        setColor(elements, color)
    })
}
function setColor(elements, color) {
  elements.forEach((element) => element.style.background = color)
}
window.onDOMContentLoaded = setupBackgroundColorChange();
```

Comment: Thank you for responding.. I tried to replace the `pretend_local_storage` with the "correct ones" but it doesn't seem to store the values in the localStorage.. I'm really not sure how to make it work. If you can please provide a working version?

Comment: @ixcode Let me know if it doesn't work. Won't let me run the API within the snippet

Comment: now the color picker doesn't work too, so I can't really test the localStorage part..

Comment: @ixcode I noticed that and have updated my answer with a fixed refactored example

Comment: Sorry, still not working really..

Comment: @ixcode It's working for me, can you explain what's happening I don't understand how it wouldn't work on your machine

Comment: OH It might be that at first local storage is undefined, and the color is undefined, so it never gets to change, trapped from the start

Comment: @ixcode Try now

Comment: Did the localStorage really worked for you? It's still not for me. I do it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ugdmfxhs/ Please check if I'm doing it wrong. I also tried putting in the `<head>` part, but it won't work too.. Thank you really!

Comment: @ixcode Fiddled around in jsfiddle with the localstorage, plz tell me this works now...

Comment: OMG finally it's working! Thank you very much!!

Comment: @ZachJensz Good Job! +1up from me!

Answer (score 1):

First of all i would use onchange trigger. To be honest, you dont need any condition inside the function. you can set the color to localStorage and that is it.

```js
/* this lines check if already set color to localStorage */
  if (window.localStorage.getItem('bgColor')) {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("card-bg")
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.background = this.value;
  }
}

function changeBgColor() {
  let color = document.getElementById('colorpicker').value;
  const bg_curr = localStorage.getItem('bgColor');
  console.log(color, bg_curr);
  localStorage.setItem('bgColor', color);
  

  document.getElementById('colorpicker').addEventListener('input', function() {

    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("card-bg")
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].style.background = color;
    }

  })

}
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => changeBgColor());
```

```css
.card1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #222;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="color" id="colorpicker" onchange="changeBgColor();">
<div class="card1 card-bg">Set A</div>
<div class="card1 card-bg">Set A</div>
<div class="card1 card-bg">Set A</div>

<br>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding.. however, the localStorage part still doesn't seem to work, I copied the above to test it..

Comment: @ixcode localStorage doesnt work in  the stackoverlfow example. security reasons. It seems that something is still wrong in your js code. you got any other errors or warnings in your console?

Comment: I copied it to my local project but is still not working sadly.. The colorpicker works fine, but it's really not saving to localStorage..

Comment: @ixcode can you select a color and check with `console.log(localStorage('bgColor'))`what the output is?

Comment: It does output something like this: `#8ca172 #729843`

Comment: @ZachJensz with this.value he have access to the changed object and that is correct but he doesnt need it because on top of the function he got the color.

Comment: @ixcode The output shows me that something was saved but it's not what I expected. probably it's the console.log from the code I included. I wonder what the problem is with you now?  I guess you want the selected colour to be displayed in the boxes on a pagereload, right?

Comment: @ZachJensz I have changed it because it is basically double.

Comment: Yes I'd like the boxes to retain their new background color on page reload and browser restart. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @ixcode Then you have to check onload if bg is already set in localstorage. if yes then set the color. i updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for all you help! That's too much time I've taken from you both, but thank you ^_^